# Dictionary values are not ordered python

Tags: python, django

When i get data from database like this:

```
filteredData = NaseljenoMesto.objects.filter(naseljenomesto_drzava=1).values('id','sifraMesta','nazivMesta','naseljenomesto_drzava__naziv')
```

Why output values are not in order like above:

Output is: `naseljenomesto_drzava__naziv,sifraMesta,nazivMesta,id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a dict that maintains insertion order, Python versions >= 2.7 include the [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class in the collections module.

A regular dict:

```
>>> ud = {}
>>> ud['first'] = 1
>>> ud['second'] = 2
>>> ud['third'] = 3
>>> ud.values()
[2, 3, 1]
```

An ordered dict:

```
>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict()
>>> od['first'] = 1
>>> od['second'] = 2
>>> od['third'] = 3
>>> od.values()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Can i somehow make an ordered dic an put inside unordered dic and then sort values?

Comment: OrderedDict is ordered by the sequence in which the (key, value) pairs are inserted. If there's some other sorting that's important to to, you'd need to handle that separately.

Answer (score 3):

A basic dictionary does not maintain insertion order. A dictionary is "ordered" by the hash values of the keys rather than the lexical values of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not maintain order.  If you want to have an ordered dictionary, check out the `collections` module from the standard library:

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict()
```

It will behave like the python dictionaries you are used to, but maintain order.

Answer (score 1):

at some point of your progress in programming, you will realize that if order matters for you, then you probably have to reconsider using a dictionary in the first place